# Better color syntax for CoffeeScript in emacs?

Tags: emacs, coffeescript

I've seen that when I write a function in coffeescript-textmate it colors the name of function

```
pleasePutMeSomeColor = () -> console.log "textmate works great!"
```

in this example pleasePutMeColor is colored inside textmate. This allows me to recognize which are functions much quicker. But when I write the same example inside emacs this word isn't colored. It is harder to identify which are functions.

Is there a way to highlight functions with a different color in emacs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yup...I'm going to answer my question:
Inside github there is a defunkt coffee-mode fork that adds syntax highlighting for functions.

https://github.com/handle/coffee-mode

It isn't perfect but works well...I hope that it will be added to the official coffe-mode repo.

Answer (score 8):

Are you using [defunkt's coffee-mode](https://github.com/defunkt/coffee-mode)? That's the only CoffeeScript syntax highlighting plugin for Emacs that I'm aware of; it's under active development, so feel free to [submit an issue](https://github.com/defunkt/coffee-mode/issues) if you have a specific suggestion.